# Como criar um Array de Strings a partir de um Array de Strings e um ArrayList de Inteiros?

Tags: android, array, arraylist, firebase-database

Estou criando um aplicativo que precisará armazenar as especialidades de cada clínica cadastrada no aplicativo, essas especialidades posteriormente armazenarei no banco de dados do Firebase, estou usando um Dialog com checkboxes onde mostrarão as especialidades da clínica, estou usando também um array de strings que possui uma referencia a um array definido no string.xml com as especialidades, e um ArrayList que salva os resultados, quais itens da lista de especialidades foram selecionados, porém não consigo converter os itens selecionados numa lista com o nome das especialidades que foram selecionadas.

No método setPositiveButton, existe um exemplo de que consigo passar as especialidades apenas para uma string comum.

[image: Dialog com as especialidades]

```
private boolean[] especialidadesChecadas;
private String[] listaEspecialidades;
private ArrayList<Integer> mEspecialidadeSelecionados = new ArrayList<>();


    botaoEspecialidades.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(redeSelecionada != null){

                AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CadastroActivity.this);
                mBuilder.setTitle("Seleciona as especialidades:")
                .setMultiChoiceItems(listaEspecialidades, especialidadesChecadas, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int position, boolean isChecked) {

                        if(isChecked){
                            if(!mEspecialidadeSelecionados.contains(position)){
                                mEspecialidadeSelecionados.add(position);
                            }
                        }   else if (mEspecialidadeSelecionados.contains(position)){
                                mEspecialidadeSelecionados.remove((Integer) position);
                                    }
                    }
                });

                mBuilder.setCancelable(false);
                mBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        String item = "";

                        for(int i= 0; i < mEspecialidadeSelecionados.size(); i++){
                            item = item + listaEspecialidades[mEspecialidadeSelecionados.get(i)];

                            if(i != mEspecialidadeSelecionados.size() -1){
                                item = item + ", ";
                            }
                        }

                        //DESSA FORMA CONSIGO VER TODAS AS ESPECIALIDADES NUMA UNICA STRING, MAS PRECISAVA 
                        //DE UM ARRAY DE STRING PARA ARMAZENAR DO FIREBASE DATABASE PARA PUXAR POSTERIORMENTE
                        Toast.makeText(CadastroActivity.this, ""+item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });

                mBuilder.setNegativeButton("Fechar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        dialog.dismiss();

                    }
                });

                mBuilder.setNeutralButton("Limpar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        //Limpar selecionados
                        //Passa por todos os itens e deseleciona
                        for(int i = 0; i < especialidadesChecadas.length; i++){
                            especialidadesChecadas[i] = false;
                            mEspecialidadeSelecionados.clear();

                        }

                    }
                });


                AlertDialog mDialog = mBuilder.create();
                mDialog.show();
```

Comment: Se precisa de um array de strings é so criar o array, algo como `List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();` e fazer `strings.add(item)` em vez do `item = item + ", ";`. Se depois precisar de construir uma string com base no array juntando os vários elementos é só usar `String.join`

Comment: Fiz o teste, porém na hora de enviar para o Firebase Database ele cria apenas uma posição e coloca todos os itens lá, exemplo: [0]: Imunologia, Ortodontia, não separa elas em outras posições. Seu eu armazenar dessa forma acho que não vou conseguir consultar por especialidades depois, já que todos estarão numa mesma posição, certo?

Comment: Adicionar num `ArrayList` com o método `add` coloca cada item numa nova posição. Agora como fica no Firebase depende de como está a atualizar a informação lá

Comment: Obrigado, consegui através de um for que percorre por todos os itens e adiciono no  List<String> especialidades.